# Instagram feed javascript on my website wont work

Tags: javascript, instagram, feed, codepen

Hey I'm trying to implement this codepen script:

https://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/zrrrLN

On my website http://mariumarif.co.uk/index.php

But it won't work **on my site**

I've generated and entered all my "client id" "secret code" etc into the codepen and it works IN the codepen with my instagram: https://www.instagram.com/mariumarif_hairstylist/

Not sure why it won't work **on my site**. Any ideas?

```js
// Use the CDN or host the script yourself
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/instafeed.js/1.4.1/instafeed.min.js
// https://matthewelsom.com/assets/js/libs/instafeed.min.js

var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: 'MY_USER_ID',
  clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
  accessToken: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  limit: 17,
  links: true
});
userFeed.run();
```

```css
#instafeed {
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#instafeed a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 580px) {
  #instafeed a {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
#instafeed a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="instafeed">
</div>
```

Comment: How it should work? What doesn't work?

Comment: This is a really bad script to begin with, exposing access tokens in client-side code is an absolute no-no. This should be done on the server-side.

Comment: The feed doesnt show on site no idea. Im not too familiar with js

Answer (score 1):

Open your console (F12).
It says :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Instafeed is not defined

So, as the instructions say ("Use the CDN or host the script yourself") include this dependency before running your code and you should be good :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/instafeed.js/1.4.1/instafeed.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks my colleague fixed it. Turns out the script was called in the wrong order I re-organised and it now works. Haha simple fix !